# Linux drains battery

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, battery, opensuse

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad L412 with a non-overclocked i5 2<sup>nd</sup> gen, 4GB RAM, and a Radeon HDv545. Whenever I use Windows and have possibly battery intensive applications running, the battery still lasts a minimum of 2.5 hours.

However, I've noticed that when I switch to Linux (I'm currently using openSUSE with power management enabled) I notice a rapid drain in battery life. Linux automatically enables Bluetooth and I must make sure it's always off when I boot my system. Does Linux enable any other features I must turn off to conserve battery?

Why does Linux drain my battery and how do I overcome this?

Comment: You might want to have a look on https://01.org/powertop/

Answer (score 0):

Torcellite, besides turning off Bluetooth, make sure you have `CPUFreq` or similar installed:

```
Package: cpufreqd
Priority: optional
Section: universe/admin
Description-en: fully configurable daemon for dynamic frequency and voltage scaling
 cpufreqd is meant to be a replacement of the speedstep applet you can find on
 some other OS, it monitors the system status and selects the most appropriate
 CPU level.  It is fully configurable and easily extensible through the many
 available plug-ins (more to come).
 Despite its name it can be used to control also the NForce2-Atxp1 voltage
 regulator and the core and memory clock for NVidia cards (see README.Debian).
 .
 You need a CPUFreq driver and either APM, ACPI (a recent version) or PMU
 enabled in your kernel in order for this daemon to work.
Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpufreqd
```

Basically it would drop your `CPU` speed when your system is idle. This will be a huge power saver, and it will cool your CPU significantly as well.

The default setting in Debian/Ubuntu is on demand, which is the best setting for personal use.